# Is Foundation imported by default?

Tags: swift

I have Cocoa Touch Framework. Each of all three following code samples as source of my Framework is successfully compilable.

```swift
import Foundation
protocol X {
    var a: Data { get }
}
```

```swift
protocol X {
    var a: Foundation.Data { get }
}
```

```swift
protocol X {
    var a: Data { get }
}
```

The last one uses type from Foundation without any importing of this module. Is Foundation imported by default into Swift file in case when module header (.h file) contains `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (generated by default)?

---

Note (30.10.19)

I removed `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and replaced `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` with `extern` in module header (.h file). After that I added `import Foundation` into my swift file. As a result only first example of code is compilable.

As I understand if module was imported into header (.h) of another module - it isn't necessary to import first module into Swift files of second module. Am I right?

Comment: I didn't ask about containing Foundation in UIKIt. Foundation can be replaced with UIKit without losing of question essence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `UIKit` imports `Foundation` so if you have `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` or `import UIKit` there is no need to import Foundation

Take a look at here in `UIKit`'s source swift code [Here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6f91a4e3ddcb3e9d4ffa040a2fa2afade90b9cdc/stdlib/public/SDK/UIKit/UIKit.swift)

**Edit**

[Here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Modules.rst#id19) is useful information about how modules work in swift,

> You can also selectively import certain declarations from a module:
>
> ```
> import func Chess.createGreedyPlayer
> import class Foundation.NSRegularExpression
> ```
>
> Comparison with Other Languages
>
> Importing  a module is much like importing a library in Ruby, Python, or Perl,
>   importing a class in Java, or including a header file in a C-family
>   language. However, unlike C, module files are not textually included
>   and must be valid programs on their own, and may not be in a textual
>   format at all. Unlike Java, declarations in a module are not visible
>   at all until imported. And unlike the dynamic languages mentioned,
>   importing a module cannot automatically cause any code to be run.

Importing a module in swift uses one of three syntaxes below:

```
import [module]
import [module].[submodule]
import [import kind] [module].[symbol name]
```

when we do not specify the import kind while importing `Data`, we’re actually still just importing the entirety of `Foundation`.

there are multiple permissible import kinds available:

```
typealias | struct | class | enum | protocol | let | var | func
```

> Like any other body of code, a module may depend on other modules in
>   its implementation. The module implementer may also choose to
>   re-export these modules, meaning that anyone who imports the first
>   module will also have access to the declarations in the re-exported
>   modules.
>
> `@exported import AmericanCheckers`
>
> As an example, the "Cocoa" framework on OS X exists only to re-export
>   three other frameworks: AppKit, Foundation, and CoreData.
>
> Just as certain declarations can be selectively imported from a
>   module, so too can they be selectively re-exported, using the same
>   syntax:
>
> `@exported import class AmericanCheckers.Board`

Comment: I didn't ask about containing Foundation in UIKIt. Foundation can be replaced with UIKit without losing of question essence. I updated my question with some details for do it clearer. Please, check.

Comment: Can you add something like "if module header import some dependency - this dependency is visible in all Swift files of this module" into your answer, please? And I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: "A module may depend on other modules in its implementation", So your answer is yes, Sift files of the module can see what are they depending on